# Overclocking the E-350 APU on Linux

Tags: linux, overclocking

Is there any way to over/underclock or change the voltages of the AMD E-350 APU on Linux?

Answer (score 1):

Undervolt with Undervolt:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/undervolt/

Load neccessary modules:

```
sudo modprobe msr
```

Get some infos:

```
sudo undervolt -r
```

Undervolt:

```
sudo undervolt -p 0:0x1C,2.00 -p 1:0x2C,2.50 -p 2:0x3C,4.00
```

P-State:Voltage_ID,Divider

Example: "0:0x1C,2.00"

P-state "0", voltage id "0x1C", divider "2.00".

You have to experiment with the values!

The values work on my pc, but that doesn't mean they work on yours too!

Answer (score 0):

There is [k10ctl](http://www.ztex.de/misc/k10ctl.e.html) which was originally build for k10 cpus but there are reports of it working with other amd cpus so could take a look and see if reads reasonable values and decide from there.

[Here](http://www.overclock.net/t/1205257/overclock-cpu-in-linux-necessary-program-names-given) is a summary of overclocking tools for linux I found helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

Undervolt with AmdMsrTweaker-Lnx:

https://github.com/johkra/amdmsrtweaker-lnx

Load neccessary modules:

```
sudo modprobe msr
sudo modprobe cpuid
```

Get some infos:

```
sudo amdmsr
```

Undervolt:

```
sudo amdmsrt P0=16@1.2 P1=12.8@1.0 P2=8@0.8 NB_P0=0.85 NB_P1=0.8
```

P-State=Multiplicator@Voltage

P0, P1, P2 are the p-states of the CPU.

NB_P0, NB_P1 are the p-states of the northbridge.

Example: "P0=16@1.2"

P-state "0", multiplicator "16", voltage "1.2" volts.

You have to experiment with the values!

The values work on my pc, but that doesn't mean they work on yours too!

Comment: Can you please explain how to use the tools in a way that answers OP's question? As it stands, this answer might be deleted as spam.